# Dynamically add row with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have an application that integrated with barcode scanner, like this:

[image]

I have made a row dynamically with this snippet of code:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" align="top" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <h1 align="center">
        Barcode: <br><input type="text" id="myHeader" value="5555">
    </h1>
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Barcode</td>
          <td>Item</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" style="text-align: left;">
            <div align="right">
              <p style="color: black;margin-right: 90px;">9.999.999</p>
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" style="border-color: black;" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is the code that I wrapped with script tag:

```
<script >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 0;

        $("#addrow").on("click", function() {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";

            cols += '<td><input type="text" disabled value="123123123" class="form-control" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" disabled value="Sekop" class="form-control" name="mail' + counter + '"/></td>';

            cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            counter++;
        });

        $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            counter -= 1
        });
    });

function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function() {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
} </script>
```

But the code above just add the row only when I clicked the **Add Row** button.

What I want for now is, when I scan a barcode with a barcode scanner, the row automatically added follow the scanned barcode result. 
In this case it will be: "When the value on barcode on the header changed ( `<h1 align="center">Barcode: 123123123</h1>` , the result is same when I clicked the **Add Row** button.

So, please refer any approach, tutorial or example code how to do that, it would be very appreciated :)

**For additional information:** The purpose of this app is for cashier app on a store, like when the cashier scan a product, the result automatically appear on the app. And I developing it using Python Flask.

Comment: Firstly check for an event when barcode scanner initiated. On initiation, you need to trigger `add row` button so it will add a new row in your table. After that you can find the last row of the table and then can replace values of `Barcode` and `Item`. Hope it helps you to finalize your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen to the changes made in the element. You can try with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#addrow").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";

    cols += '<td><input type="text" disabled value="123123123" class="form-control" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" disabled value="Sekop" class="form-control" name="mail' + counter + '"/></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });

  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1
  });
});

function calculateRow(row) {
  var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
  var grandTotal = 0;
  $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function() {
      grandTotal += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}

// Listen to the changes in the header element and add row
var target = document.querySelector('#myHeader');

setTimeout(function() {
  target.textContent = "New Barcode: XXXXXXXXX"; // change text after 2 seconds
}, 2000)

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    $("#addrow").trigger("click"); // trigger the click event to add row if the header text is changed
  });
});

var config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  characterData: true
};

observer.observe(target, config);

// otherwise
observer.disconnect();
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" align="top" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <h1 align="center" id="myHeader">Barcode: 123123123</h1>
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Barcode</td>
          <td>Item</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" style="text-align: left;">
            <div align="right">
              <p style="color: black;margin-right: 90px;">9.999.999</p>
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" style="border-color: black;" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Update:** The updated question indicates that you can trigger the click event on blur event of the barcode input element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0;

  $("#addrow").on("click", function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    var barcode = $("#myHeader").val().trim();// take the current barcode value
    cols += '<td><input type="text" disabled value= '+ barcode +'  class="form-control" name="name' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text" disabled value="Sekop" class="form-control" name="mail' + counter + '"/></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
  });

  $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function(event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    counter -= 1
  });
});

function calculateRow(row) {
  var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
  var grandTotal = 0;
  $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function() {
      grandTotal += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}

// Add new row by triggering the click event on focus out
var target = document.querySelector('#myHeader');
target.addEventListener('blur', function(){
  $("#addrow").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" align="top" style="margin-top: 0px;">
    Barcode: <br><input type="text" id="myHeader" value="5555">
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Barcode</td>
          <td>Item</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="7" style="text-align: left;">
            <div align="right">
              <p style="color: black;margin-right: 90px;">9.999.999</p>
            </div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" style="border-color: black;" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it just works first time (after refresh browser), what if I added the new barcode..?

Comment: @GofyandKitty, by seeing the updated question it seems that you do not need the mutation observer. You can simply trigger the click event on focus out (`blur`) event of the element. I have updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myTable tbody').append(newRow)
```

I think you have problem with your jQuery selector.

Try the code shown above - hope it works for you.